# how to update container view from embedded view container in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

pass variables from embedded view controller to container view controller and after update container will update parent view contoller

[image]

```
@IBAction func updateLabel(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContViewController") as! ContViewController
        vc.labelName.text = textFieldValue.text
        
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Total new learner so tried this which I understand but not getting success so any one can help me in this

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: containerView is not updating

Comment: Please elaborate (edit your question). What is not updating? What is the code you show supposed to do?